# What does the following sequence converge to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**Does the following sequence converge or diverge? If it converges, find its limit.**

$\frac{1^1}{n^2}+\frac{2^1}{n^2}+........+\frac{n^1}{n^2}$

I tried to get a general formula for this sequence and simply got:

$\frac{n}{n^2}$ or $\frac{1}{n}$

This led me to think that the sequence converges to $0$ since the limit of this function is $0$. But this limit is incorrect. This tells me the general formula I got for the sequence is incorrect. But I am not sure why.

Any help?

Comment: `the general formula I got for the sequence is incorrect` True. `But I am not sure why` That can't be answered unless you post the steps.

Comment: What you have is $\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n k}{n^2} = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}$

Comment: What have you got? Show it to us and we would help you find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to calculate the following $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2}$$
It is equal to $$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n k}{n^2}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = {n(n+1)\over 2}$$
$$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n k}{n^2} = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}= \dfrac{(n+1)}{2n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{(n+1)}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = {n(n+1)\over 2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is a Riemann sum. To be more precise, it is the upper sum of the function $f(x)=x$ defined on $[0,1]$ with respect to the partition $\left\{0,\frac1n,\frac2n,\ldots,\frac nn(=1)\right\}$. Therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}+\frac2{n^2}+\cdots+\frac n{n^2}=\int_0^1x\,\mathrm dx=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 2):

By [Stolz Cesàro](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+2+3+...+ n}{n^2}$$

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{2n+1}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Your first correction was spot on.  The top limit is, in the second line: $$= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+1}{2n}$$  Too bad you reverted to the original post.

Comment: I second doubted myself, but when I took the time to do it on paper, I’m pretty sure my original thought was right. With $b_n=n^2$ and $a_n=1+2+...+n$, $b_{n+1}-b_{n}=(n+1)^2-n^2=n^2+2n+1-n^2=2n+1$. @amWhy

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^2}+........+\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac1{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k$$

then recall that $\sum_{k=1}^n k = {n(n+1)\over 2}$.

More in general for

$$\frac{1^p}{n^{p+1}}+\frac{2^p}{n^{p+1}}+........+\frac{n^p}{n^{p+1}}=\frac1{n^{p+1}} \sum_{k=1}^n k^p$$

and by [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^p \sim \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}$$